# What is the resulting big oh for this expression?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series

I'm new to big-oh notation and working with its arithmetic. If I'm given the following

$a=O(\delta^2),\quad b=O(\delta^2),\quad c=O(\delta^2),\quad d=O(\alpha^2)$

What is the the resulting big-oh for the following expression if $(\alpha \rightarrow 0,\delta \rightarrow 0)$? For the sake of further understanding, how about $(\alpha \rightarrow \infty,\delta \rightarrow \infty )$?

$$\displaystyle \frac{a^2}{d^2}\frac{(1-c^2\frac{c}{a})}{(1-b^2)}$$

I understand there are wikipedia pages and other sources explaining the arithmetic, but I can not follow. I need to learn by example. Please show how the powers, products, etc. influence the orders. I will later have to change the orders of $a,b,c,d$ and I need to know the correct way to find the resulting big-oh of the expression. For example, I have to also find the result of

$a=O(\delta^4),\quad b=O(\delta^4),\quad c=O(\delta^2),\quad d=O(\alpha^2)$

But again, if you can show by example with the expression I've given and highlight the arithmetic, I should be fine moving forward.

EDIT: I made changes based on the comments. I've also changed $d=O(\delta^2)$ to $d=O(\alpha^2)$ since it depends on another variable. The root of this question comes from expressions for the truncation error. For example the variable $a$ is expressed as a truncated Taylor series to $O(\delta^2)$. All variables are truncated series expressions, but I don't understand how the truncation of each variable effects the final truncation of the expression. Please let me know if there is more I need to clarify.

Comment: I think those exponents should be inside the brackets: $O(\delta^2)$ rather than $O(\delta)^2$.

Comment: Also, please specify whether $\delta \rightarrow 0$ or $\delta \rightarrow \infty$.  (The big $O$ notation is always asymptotic, with the argument tending either toward a finite value or toward infinity.)

Comment: Based on the comments, I tried to improve my question. Thanks for bringing those to my attention

Answer (score 2):

You can't answer this question, because the ratio of two functions known by an upper bound only (Big-$O$) is indeterminate.

For instance, both $\delta=O(\delta^2)$ and $\frac1{\delta^{27}}=O(\delta^2)$ hold, while $$\dfrac\delta{\frac1{\delta^{27}}}=\delta^{28}.$$

Actually, Big-$\Theta$ is required.

Comment: so you're assuming $\delta \to \infty$ right?

Comment: @Surb: otherwise my equalities would be wrong. But the same argument would hold for $\delta\to0$.